# How to concatenate at least three 2-D array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, encoding, pytorch

I am doing goal-oriented image captioning. It has three modalities- features extracted, OCR component and object detection. The features extracted from ResNeXt model is reshaped into a tensor of size (49, 2048). The OCR and Object Detection components have a maximum of 20 and 10 words respectively, each of dimension (300,1). I want to concatenate/embed these vectors into a joint space of dimension d=512 using linear projection. How can I do this?

I used numpy.concatenate function with axis=None, it concatenated the output linearly and had a dimension of 100652 but I want the output as mentioned above with (512,n) as I have to pass the concatenated output to decoder.

Comment: There's no `np.cat` function.  `np.concatenate` lets (encourages) you to specify an `axis` (besides `None`), but you have to understand the dimensions of your component arrays.  If the arrays are all 2d (really 2d, check the shape), you can use axis 0 (default) or 1.  Show a sample - especially the `shape` (and `dtype`).  Your word description of dimensions is hard to follow.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I meant np.concatenate only, mentioned it wrongly here but I did it properly in the code. And for sample, with shape and dtype exactly as obtained from the code's output is as follows:

The feature vector has shape of (49, 2048) and dtype is float32.
The word vector (encoded by fastText) has shape of (300,1) and dtype is float32, each. As in, each word has this shape (and dtype) and we have many words as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating `concatenate` with different `axis`:

```
In [32]: alist = [np.ones((2,4),int)*i for i in range(1,4)]
In [33]: alist
Out[33]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]]),
 array([[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]),
 array([[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]])]
In [34]: np.concatenate(alist,axis=0)
Out[34]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
In [35]: np.concatenate(alist,axis=1)
Out[35]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
In [36]: np.concatenate(alist,axis=None)
Out[36]: 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3])
```

Is that any different from what you expect from reading the docs?

Comment: Well, thank you! I was able to understand this from the document but I was unclear on how to change the shape after concatenation but I am assuming after concatenation by an axis, it would be possible for us to reshape in the way we want accordingly. Is my understanding correct?